# How to display geojson data on browser from mongodb using mongoengine and django rest api

Tags: geojson, geodjango, django

I have stored my geojson data on mongodb.
which contains properties and polygon of a area.

{

"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [

```
{

  "type": "Feature",

  "properties": {

    "Year": 2015,

    "High_Temperature": 32,

    "Low_Temperature": 22,

    "Precipitation_In_mm": 3.5,
    "Snow_In_cm": 0,
    "Average_High_Temperature": 31,
    "Average_Low_Temperature": 21,
    "Season": "Kharif",
    "CROP": "PADDY",
    "DISTRICT": "PUNE",
    "TALUKA": "HAVELI",
    "CIRCLE": "URALIKANCHAN",
    "AY05": "",
    "AY06": 1383.9,
    "AY07": 1914.7,
    "AY08": 1952.5,
    "AY09": 1028.5,
    "AY10": 1805.5,
    "AY11": 1146.1,
    "AY12": 1043,
    "AY13": 1315.1,
    "AY14": 2267.6,
    "AY15": 1428.2,
    "Area_In_Hector": 553,
    "SI_2012_2013_In_Rs": "",
    "Premium_2012_2013": "",
    "SI_2013_2014_In_Rs": "",
    "Premium_2013_2014": "",
    "SI_2014_2015_In_Rs": "",
    "Premium_2014_2015": "",
    "SI_2015_2016_In_Rs": "",
    "Premium_2015_2016": "",
    "SI_2016_2017_In_Rs": 39000,
    "Sum_Insured_2011_to_2015": "",
    "Compensation_Paid_In_lakh": "",
    "Farmer": ""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          74.129992,
          18.505494
        ],
        [
          74.129047,
          18.505494
        ],
        [
          74.128275,
          18.504436
        ],
        [
          74.127588,
          18.503052
        ],
        [
          74.123125,
          18.496622
        ],
        [
          74.122095,
          18.496378
        ],
        [
          74.121151,
          18.496459
        ],
        [
          74.119692,
          18.496703
        ],
        [
          74.118319,
          18.49711
        ],
        [
          74.117117,
          18.497517
        ],
        [
          74.115744,
          18.498006
        ],
        [
          74.114971,
          18.49825
        ],
        [
          74.114456,
          18.498331
        ],
        [
          74.113941,
          18.498331
        ],
        [
          74.113512,
          18.49768
        ],
        [
          74.112997,
          18.496378
        ],
        [
          74.11274,
          18.495157
        ],
        [
          74.112482,
          18.493773
        ],
        [
          74.112053,
          18.491494
        ],
        [
          74.111624,
          18.48954
        ],
        [
          74.11128,
          18.487994
        ],
        [
          74.111109,
          18.487505
        ],
        [
          74.111452,
          18.486691
        ],
        [
          74.111881,
          18.485552
        ],
        [
          74.114714,
          18.480912
        ],
        [
          74.116945,
          18.477818
        ],
        [
          74.118919,
          18.475783
        ],
        [
          74.12055,
          18.47354
        ],
        [
          74.121666,
          18.471875
        ],
        [
          74.128103,
          18.467072
        ],
        [
          74.129734,
          18.466747
        ],
        [
          74.143381,
          18.467316
        ],
        [
          74.143553,
          18.4687
        ],
        [
          74.143724,
          18.473992
        ],
        [
          74.144497,
          18.474888
        ],
        [
          74.145269,
          18.476027
        ],
        [
          74.15617,
          18.486854
        ],
        [
          74.155912,
          18.488319
        ],
        [
          74.145956,
          18.502564
        ],
        [
          74.14278,
          18.503866
        ],
        [
          74.129992,
          18.505412
        ],
        [
          74.129992,
          18.505494
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

]
}

Now I want to display that data on browser using mongoengine and Django rest api.
I have already connect my other data with Django using mongoengine but I don't know how to connect geojson data and how to display it on browser using Django and mongoengine.
I don't know what to write in models,settings and views file for this.